# Configure GWT compilation from ANT

Tags: gwt, gwt2

The gwt.xml associated with a module controls the configuration for how the app is compiled. This is great if there will only ever be one configuration for the app. My dilemma lies in the fact that I have one code base, but many configurations.  My solution to date has been to pre-process the gwt.xml using [Freemarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/index.html), which in my mind is sub-ideal. Is there a method of passing the ant environment or a set of configuration options to the GWT compiler so that I can use conditionals in the gwt.xml itself?

Comment: See http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=3466

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Maven GWT Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/). It allows you to do exactly that and much more.

Comment: Can you expand on that a bit more? The list of features I see on the link you have doesn't include anything about dynamic configuration of gwt.xml...